# tensorflow how to merge batchnorm into convolution for faster inference

Tags: tensorflow

is there a way (code scripts) for merging tensorflow batchnorm and dropout layer into convolution layer in inference for faster computation?

I have searched a while, but not got relevant answers.

Answer (score 9):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no built-in feature in TensorFlow for folding batch normalization. That being said, it's not that hard to do it manually. One note, there is no such thing as *folding dropout* as dropout is simply deactivated at inference time.

To fold batch normalization there is basically three steps:

1. Given a TensorFlow graph, filter the variables that need folding,
2. Fold the variables,
3. Create a new graph with the folded variables.

We need to filter the variables that require folding. When using batch normalization, it creates variables with names containing `moving_mean` and `moving_variance`. You can use this to extract fairly easily the variables from layers that used batch norm.

Now that you know which layers used batch norm, for every such layer, you can extract its weights `W`, bias `b`, batch norm variance `v`, mean `m`, `gamma` and `beta` parameters.  You need to create a new variable to store the folded weights and biases as follow:

```py
W_new = gamma * W / var
b_new = gamma * (b - mean) / var + beta
```

The last step consists in creating a new graph in which we deactivate batch norm and add `bias` variables if necessary –which should be the case for every foldable layer since using bias with batch norm is pointless.

The whole code should look something like below. Depending on the parameters used for the batch norm, your graph may not have `gamma` or `beta`.

```py
# ****** (1) Get variables ******
variables = {v.name: session.run(v) for v in tf.global_variables()}

# ****** (2) Fold variables ******
folded_variables = {}
for v in variables.keys():
    if not v.endswith('moving_variance:0'):
        continue

    n = get_layer_name(v) # 'model/conv1/moving_variance:0' --> 'model/conv1'

    W = variable[n + '/weights:0'] # or "/kernel:0", etc.
    b = variable[n + '/bias:0'] # if a bias existed before
    gamma = variable[n + '/gamma:0']
    beta = variable[n + '/beta:0']
    m = variable[n + '/moving_mean:0']
    var = variable[n + '/moving_variance:0']

    # folding batch norm
    W_new = gamma * W / var
    b_new = gamma * (b - mean) / var + beta # remove `b` if no bias
    folded_variables[n + '/weights:0'] = W_new        
    folded_variables[n + '/bias:0'] = b_new   

    # ****** (3) Create new graph ******
    new_graph = tf.Graph()
    new_session = tf.Session(graph=new_graph) 
    network = ... # instance batch-norm free graph with bias added.
                  # Careful, the names should match the original model

    for v in tf.global_variables():
        try:
            new_session.run(v.assign(folded_variables[v.name]))
        except:
            new_session.run(v.assign(variables[v.name]))
```

Comment: I will just add a line here for others because it took sometime for me understand your solution.  x' = Wx + b. In batch norm, during testing, we change x' to (x' - population_mean) / population_var * scale + beta. Now by replacing x' with Wx + b, one can see that the new_weights defined @BiBi actually make sense.

Comment: It might indeed help to look at the batch norm transformation to understand the folding. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, i am working on the same thing here and stumbeled accros this. I tried to get the same results before and after folding and realized that the results don't match with your formular. Looking at how batchnorm is computed (https://medium.com/deeplearningmadeeasy/everything-you-wish-to-know-about-batchnorm-6055e07fdce2) i realized that you are missing the sqrt and the epsilon.  
``w_new = gamma * w / np.sqrt(var + epsilon);
b_new = gamma * (b - mean) / np.sqrt(var + epsilon) + beta)``

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool provided by tensorflow that optimizes your trained frozen graph for inference: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#fold_batch_norms

1. download tensorflow source.
2. build graph transform tool.

   ```
   bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph
   ```
3. freeze your graph. e.g., https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc
4. run this:

   ```
   bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
   --in_graph=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb \
   --out_graph=optimized_inception_graph.pb \
   --inputs='Mul' \
   --outputs='softmax' \
   --transforms='
     strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3")
     remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
     fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
     fold_batch_norms
     fold_old_batch_norms'
   ```

Comment: If I have my own model which is CNN Regression model, then will the above method using bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \  work ? Will it work just by changing outputs = 'softmax' to outputs='regression'  and giving the shape as required? Or is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @PradyumnaTK yes it will work by changing the `--inputs` and `--output` options. You can use netron (https://netron.app/) to visualize your frozen graph and get the input/output names for nodes.